# iOS Splashscreen not Centering Logo in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

On a Mac, I designed the screen in a sample project using Xcode and copy the result into the splashscreen in VS2022 (Windows).  The code works as expected running in Xcode.  However, when running in VS2022, the screen display correctly in portrait mode but not in landscape.  It appears this that the view isn't aware that the device is in landscape mode.  If you compare the images, you will see that the icon is positioned in landscape as if it was in portrait.  See composite.

I have tried constraints to superview for both X and Y without success too.

So why does it work running on Mac/Xcode and not Windows/VS2022/Xamarin?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="landscape" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="zO9-mi-WmR">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="896" height="414"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="square.and.arrow.down.on.square.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="i2f-xz-yXe">
                                <rect key="frame" x="385.5" y="132.5" width="125" height="129"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="125" id="iSs-Y6-u1b"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="125" id="knT-iP-1d2"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="9TD-vu-rqU"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="i2f-xz-yXe" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="9TD-vu-rqU" secondAttribute="centerY" id="TIc-QI-zib"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="i2f-xz-yXe" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="9TD-vu-rqU" secondAttribute="centerX" id="cVF-vS-Ss8"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="131.25" y="95.652173913043484"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="square.and.arrow.down.on.square.fill" catalog="system" width="122" height="128"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

[portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3fah.png) [landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60WTr.png) [composite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02o58.png)

Comment: If you are testing on Simulator, then test on an actual device. I don't know why it behaves differently launched from VS Windows, but I wouldn't conclude anything (about this topic) from behavior on a simulator.

Comment: can you try it secondItem="zO9-mi-WmR" plz change this 2 lines:
 <constraint firstItem="i2f-xz-yXe" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="zO9-mi-WmR" secondAttribute="centerY" id="TIc-QI-zib"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="i2f-xz-yXe" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="zO9-mi-WmR" secondAttribute="centerX" id="cVF-vS-Ss8"/>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't fix the issue.  I will try to test on an actual device and get back.

Comment: ToolmakerSteve, you were correct.  Thanks. It worked fine when deployed to an actual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't trust the simulator, use an actual device.

Comment: If you find the root cause as suggested by ToolmakerSteve, you can mark it as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks!